# is it possible to make "beep" sound in php like in gmail

Tags: php, html, audio

for an IM script i am making, 
i would like the computer to beep like in gmail everytime there is a new message. 
is there a script in php or html to make the computer beep?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's the computer who's beeping. Else might have a problem with your sound card. It's just some sound played using flash.

Comment: I'd drop the PHP if I were you. Playing sound via javascript and flash is interesting enough as it is.

Comment: Since PHP is a server-side language, the user would never hear it because the server would be doing the beeping, not the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is load a small flash movie that makes the sound, you can easily toggle it in your page with Javascript whenever you need it.

Comment: I have disabled flash plugin on IE8 but chat beep sound is still remains. How Gmail achieves  to do this without flash? Notice that this has been done even without using ActiveX object on IE8.

Answer (score 6):

Several popular javascript libraries have interfaces for playing sounds built in or available as plugins, for example see [Scriptaculous](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/sound) and [jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound).

Answer (score 0):

**you can use html to play beep sound in background**

**just copy and paste:**

```
echo "<audio src='http://freesoundeffect.net/sites/default/files/incorrect-answer--6-sound-effect-99679566.mp3' autoplay ></audio>";
```

> this code play beep sound in background and you can change .mp3 file